# jQuery .click() doesn't work offline?

Tags: jquery, offline

I've bind .click events on some section headers, so that when a user clicks on one of those headers, the section appears/disappears.

So far so good, but for some reason, when I go offline, that doesn't work anymore.

I don't understand such a behaviour, could anyone enlighten me?

Here's the code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
    $(function(){

    $("#contactInfoHeader").click(function(){
        if($("#contactInformation").is(":visible")){        
            $("#contactInformation").fadeOut();
        }else{  
            $("#contactInformation").fadeIn();
        }   
        resizeWidget();
    });

    });
    </script>

    <h3 id="contactInfoHeader">Contact Information</h3>
    <div id="contactInformation">Telephone:XXXXXX</div>
```

Comment: Post how you're loading jQuery.  Does any jQuery code work?

Comment: jQuery works fine online, please see my updated question

Comment: So the usage model is: You go to the page, it works, you "go offline," and that *same page* stops working? What do you mean by "go offline"? (Different browsers and different OS's have different ideas...)

Comment: By offline I mean: no connection to the Internet (by which I'm accessing the application). I basically hit "Work offline" on Firefox or IE.

Comment: Whether you're online or not has no bearing on client side javascript behavior. Check whether or not jquery is correctly loaded when offline. Look in firebug's script tab. Is jquery there?

Comment: Yes jQuery is there when I go offline. I tried to set an alert right at the beginning of the handler, it works online and not offline. My jQuery UI Tabs are still working offline.

Comment: What does resizeWidget() do? Try providing a complete minimal test case that fails, it would help a lot.

Comment: @Pedro, it seems you're not specifically stating whether you reload the page AFTER going online. Please specify which of the two following situations is your problem: 1. You have a running app, you click 'Work offline' and right after that, without reloading or refreshing your app stops working. OR: 2. You put your browser in offline mode, surf to the page (or refresh) and after that, the app doesn't work. Please specify.

Answer (score 2):

in jQuery 1.4.x you should use this format for attaching handlers to the ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //add your stuff here
});
```

or your can keep the $(handler); syntax, **but you'll need the closing paren**.

```
<script>
$(function(){

  $("#contactInfoHeader").click(function(){
      if($("#contactInformation").is(":visible")){        
          $("#contactInformation").fadeOut();
      }else{  
          $("#contactInformation").fadeIn();
      }   
      resizeWidget();
  });

});//ADDED ")" here!
</script>
```

Comment: This is the solution. @pedro: you need to make sure to wait for all tags to be loaded, otherwise your selector will just return an empty collection and not raise an error.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been clear: jQuery DOES work when online. I just forgot to include my closing parenthesis while editing my question. The problem only appears as soon as I check "Work offline"

Answer (score 2):

Dear, you are using simple jQuery and it uses its online file. So it's functional when you are online, but offline the button stops working. That's it. It's so simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have some code inconsistency, or you're mistaken it works.

That should be in document.ready, as well:

```
$(function() {
/* your code */
});
```

Otherwise it doesn't attach the click event to anything, since the element is not there at runtime.

Comment: jQuery works correctly when online, I just forgot to post the whole thing. Please see my updated question.

Comment: jQuery sources are locally stored. No errors showing up in Firebug.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Try `alert`s and make sure code is executing.

Comment: I checked in Firebug and jQuery is still loaded when I'm offline. I set an alert right at the beginning of the handler: it works online but not offline. Also, my jQuery UI Tabs are working online & offline.